# NullPointerException from Canvas class(J2ME)

Tags: java, arrays, timer, java-me, midp

i'm having trouble from fetching data from my TimerCan class. like String and integers.

i have a method(static method) for getting this data and set it to another class. but every time i run my program i always get NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION in line..

```
    if(opp.equalsIgnoreCase("incrementing")){///heree

        startTimer();

        if(hour[current]==hhh&&min[current]==mmm&&sec[current]==sss)
        {
            this.start = false;
            this.stop = true;
            this.timer.cancel();

    }
    else if(opp.equalsIgnoreCase("decrementing")){
        startTimerD();

        if(hour[current]==0&&min[current]==0&&sec[current]==0)
        {
            this.start = false;
            this.stop = true;
            this.timer.cancel();
```

and heres the full code my TimerCan class

```
       public class TimerCan extends Canvas
{
      private Timer timer;
      private Midlet myMid;
      private Player z;
      private int hour[],sec[],min[],msec[],maxX,maxY,current,length,x,y;
      private String time,opp;
      private int strWid,hhh,mmm,sss;
     private int strht; 
     private boolean start;
     private boolean stop;
   public Image img;
Data data;

public TimerCan(Midlet midlet)
{
    this.myMid= midlet;
    data = new Data();

    opp=data.getData();
    hhh=data.getDatah();
    mmm=data.getDatam();
    sss=data.getDatas();

    try
    {
        this.maxX = this.getWidth();
        this.maxY = this.getHeight();
        this.current = 0;
        this.hour = new int[30];
        this.min = new int[30];
        this.sec = new int[30];
        this.msec = new int[30];
        this.start = false;
        this.stop = true;
        for(int j = 0  ; j <= 30 ; j++)
        {
            this.hour[j] = 0;
            this.min[j] = 0;
            this.sec[j] = 0;
            this.msec[j] = 0;
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{       
    Font font = Font.getFont(0,1,16);
    this.strWid =  font.stringWidth("this.time");
    this.strht = font.getHeight();
         if(hour[current] < 10)
        {
            time = "0"+String.valueOf(this.hour[current])+":";
        }
        else
        {
            time = String.valueOf(this.hour[current]) + ":";  
        }
        if(min[current] < 10)
        {
            time = time+"0"+String.valueOf(this.min[current]) + ":";
        }
        else
        {
            time = time+String.valueOf(this.min[current]) + ":";
        }
        if(sec[current] < 10)
        {
            time = time+"0"+String.valueOf(this.sec[current]) + ":";
        }
        else
        {
            time = time + String.valueOf(this.sec[current]) + ":";
        }
        if(msec[current] < 10)
        {
            time = time+"0"+String.valueOf(this.msec[current]);
        }
        else
        {
            time = time+String.valueOf(this.msec[current]);
        }

    this.strWid =  font.stringWidth(time);
    this.length =  this.maxX - this.strWid;
    this.length /= 2;
    try{
         img = Image.createImage("/picture/aa.png");
    }
    catch(Exception error){
    }
     x = this.getWidth()/2;
     y = this.getHeight()/2;
    g.setColor(63,155,191);
    g.fillRect(0,0,maxX, maxY);
    g.drawImage(img, x, y, Graphics.VCENTER | Graphics.HCENTER);
    g.setColor(0,0,0) ;                                               
    g.drawString(time,length+15,150,Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
}
private void startTimer()
{
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           msec[current]++ ;
            if(msec[current] == 100)
            {
                msec[current] = 0 ;
                sec[current]++ ;
            }
            else if(sec[current] ==60)
            {

                sec[current] = 0 ;
                min[current]++ ;
            }
            else if(min[current] == 60)
            {
                min[current] = 0 ;

               hour[current]++ ;
            }
            else if(hour[current] == 24)
            {
                hour[current] = 0 ;
            } 
                   repaint();
        } 
    };  
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,10,10) ;           
}
    private void startTimerD()
{
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           msec[current]-- ;
            if(msec[current] == 0)
            {
                msec[current] = 100 ;
                sec[current]-- ;
            }
            else if(sec[current] ==0)
            {

                sec[current] = sss;
                min[current]--;
            }
            else if(min[current] == 0)
            {
                min[current] =mmm;

               hour[current]--;
            }
            else if(hour[current] == 0)
            {
                hour[current] = hhh;
            } 
                   repaint();
        } 
    };  
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,10,10) ;           
}
protected  void keyPressed(int keyCode)
{
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM1)
    {
        if(this.start == false)
        {
            this.start=true;
            this.stop=false;
        }
        else if(this.stop == false)
        {
            this.start = false ;
            this.stop = true ;
            this.timer.cancel();
        }
        if(start == true)
        {
             check();
        }
    }
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM2)
    {                 
        this.min[current]=0;
        this.sec[current]=0;
        this.msec[current]=0;       
        this.start = false;
        this.stop = true;
        this.timer.cancel();
        try{
        z.deallocate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        repaint();
    }
    if(keyCode == Canvas.KEY_NUM3)
        {
            if(this.stop == false)
            {
            this.start = false;
            this.stop = true;
            this.timer.cancel();
            try{
                InputStream inss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm.wav");
                InputStreamReader iis= new InputStreamReader(inss);  
                z = Manager.createPlayer(inss,"audio/x-wav");
                z.prefetch();
                z.setLoopCount(2);
                z.start();
                }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
            }
        }
    if(keyCode==Canvas.KEY_NUM0)
    {
        try{
        z.deallocate();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        myMid.exit();
    }
 }

public void check()
{
    if(opp.equalsIgnoreCase("incrementing")){

        startTimer();

        if(hour[current]==hhh&&min[current]==mmm&&sec[current]==sss)
        {
            this.start = false;
            this.stop = true;
            this.timer.cancel();
            try{
                InputStream inss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm.wav");
                InputStreamReader iis= new InputStreamReader(inss);  
                z = Manager.createPlayer(inss,"audio/x-wav");
                z.prefetch();
                z.setLoopCount(2);
                z.start();
                }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
        }
    }
    else if(opp.equalsIgnoreCase("decrementing")){
        startTimerD();

        if(hour[current]==0&&min[current]==0&&sec[current]==0)
        {
            this.start = false;
            this.stop = true;
            this.timer.cancel();
            try{
                InputStream inss = getClass().getResourceAsStream("alarm.wav");
                InputStreamReader iis= new InputStreamReader(inss);  
                z = Manager.createPlayer(inss,"audio/x-wav");
                z.prefetch();
                z.setLoopCount(2);
                z.start();
                }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
        }
```

and heres the Data classs

public class Data{

```
String nameD;
int hhD;
int mmD;
int ssD;
public void setData(String name){ 
    this.nameD = name; 
}
public String getData(){ 
    return this.nameD; 
}
//hour
public void setDatah(int hhh){ 
    this.hhD = hhh; 
}
public int getDatah(){ 
    return this.hhD; 
}
//
public void setDatam(int hhh){ 
    this.mmD = hhh; 
}
public int getDatam(){ 
    return this.mmD; 
}
//
public void setDatas(int sss){ 
    this.ssD = sss; 
}
public int getDatas(){ 
    return this.ssD; 
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a constructor for your `Data` class?  And if so, does it set the values of the fields returned by `getData()`, `getDatah()`, `getDatam()` and `getDatas()`?  If neither of these is the case, then `opp, hhh, mmm, sss` are all going to be null, and you'll get a null pointer exception whenever you try to use any of them.

Comment: how do i do that?? i'm a bit confused with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
data = new Data();
```

in your `TimerCan` class.  This made a `Data` object that didn't have `nameD` set to anything; so when you wrote

```
opp = data.getData()
```

later, you were setting `opp` to `null` - that is, there wasn't actually an object referenced by `opp`.  When you wrote

```
if (opp.equalsIgnoreCase("incrementing"))
```

this caused a problem.  You can't call a method, when the object that you're trying to call it on is absent.

If it's legitimate for `opp` to be null, but you still have code that you want to run when `opp` is `"incrementing"` you can write it like this.

```
if (opp != null && opp.equalsIgnoreCase("incrementing"))
```

which will check whether `opp` is null *before* it calls the `equalsIgnoreCase` method - and you won't get the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: thank you for the response. now in order to use the data i est from another class check it first if it equal to null...

Comment: and theres another NULLpointer =__=, why it is null? in this line.....this.timer.cancel();

Comment: Well, that would generally indicate that you haven't set `timer` to anything when that line is running.  Seriously, I strongly recommend you use a debugger to sort out that kind of thing.

Comment: but i dunno how to debug.

Comment: Fair enough.  I hope this doesn't sound patronising, but I think it's very important for you to learn how.  A debugger is a crucial tool for any programmer to know how to wield, and use of a debugger _ought_ to be included near the beginning of every programming syllabus.  A programmer who doesn't know how to use a debugger is like a builder who doesn't know how to use a hammer.

Comment: yes, i know what debugging is, but all i can see in my codes are syntax wise but lot of errors behind it.

Comment: OK, but if you run this program with a debugger, you can put a breakpoint on the line that's throwing the exception.  Then you can look at each variable name and see what its value is, just before the exception is thrown.  This will save you _hours_.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you  have not initialized variable `data`, so it remains `null`. This is the obvious reason of `NullPointerException`.

You have to call `data = new Data();` prior using it.

Comment: at if(opp.equalsIgnoreCase("incrementing")){

Comment: this means that your `opp` is not initialized too.

Comment: you mean,,,, this?  opp=data.getData();